# Permissions on /var/log/httpd

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

I'm trying to arrange for the permissions on /var/log/httpd to be set so that httpd can write its log files there, but I can't seem to make it work. I've `chown`ed the directory to apache:apache, and `chmod`ed it 777:

```
# ls -l /var/log
[...]
drwxrwxrwx 2 apache apache    4096 Aug 26 15:55 httpd
```

So why the heck can't the apache user write files to that directory?

```
# sudo -u apache touch /var/log/httpd/foo
touch: cannot touch `/var/log/httpd/foo': Permission denied
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apache user needs to be able to traverse the directory tree to /var/log/httpd so ensure that at some permission level each of the directories /var, /var/log and /var/log/httpd have an `x` bit set that will allow this.

Check that there are no acls set that affect the apache user [getfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl) can help you determine this.

Check that there are no extended file attributes that are affecting the apache user [lsattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsattr) with explanation in the [chattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) manual.

Comment: Ah, thanks, needed a `chmod +x /var/log`. Thanks!

Comment: I think parent directories need both `+rx`, and not just `+x`. Believe it or not, Microsoft does a much better job than Linux here. Linux has to allow the process to walk the parent paths. Microsoft has a permission [Bypass traverse checking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221950(v=ws.11).aspx) that allows a program like Apache to jump right to `/var/log/httpd` without providing access to the the parent paths. Also see [Unix/Linux equivalent of Windows' Bypass Traverse Checking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176336/56041)  on U&L.SE.